# AngularJS loaded twice with Rails asset pipeline

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have set up rails to use bower according to the following guide: http://joelencioni.com/blog/2014/01/03/integrating-bower-with-rails/

I have installed AngularJS and included it in my application.js file.

Now, when I run `rake assets:precompile`, I get the following error in the console:

```
WARNING: Tried to load angular more than once.
```

But my application continues to (seemingly) work fine. When I run `rake assets:clobber`, I no longer get the error.

I read through the many StackOverflow questions and answers relating to this error and still couldn't find a solution. `ng-app` is only declared once, there are no errors with my templates and how I include them, turbolinks is removed, etc.

What could cause this error when I compile my assets?

**UPDATE:** Some strange behaviour here... running the app in production with Passenger, the above error doesn't show up.